# How can I get the bottom padding of an input working in IE8?

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-8

I am running a site inside of an application viewer. This viewer will render the website in IE8 compatibility mode which I have no control over and can't change.

I have an `input` with top/bottom `padding` of 6px and left/right `padding` of 12px, but for some weird reason the `bottom padding` is ignored and the `padding` is incorrect.

Here is a screenshot of what I'm seeing:

[image]

Here is the CSS I'm using to style the `input` field:

```
input[type="text"] {
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 6px 12px 6px 12px;
    *padding: 6px 12px 6px 12px;
}
```

I have Googled around for a while now and can't seem to be able to find a solution to my problem. Many tips I found suggest to use various `line-height` adjustments, while some suggest to use `*padding: 6px 12px 6px 12px;`. None of these tips work and the issue still exists.

How can I force the input to have equal top and bottom padding in IE8?

**Note:** I CANNOT use the `http-equiv` meta tag as it will cause other problems with the viewer.

Comment: have you tried to set an `height` ?

Comment: @GCyrillus yes that works but I am trying to figure out what the padding is not working?

Comment: Just an FYI: microsoft has stopped supporting ie10 and below https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/WindowsForBusiness/End-of-IE-support

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith yes I realize that. If I had the option I would dump IE altogether but in my case I am restricted to what the viewer will allow me to do

Comment: form elements can only be partialy styled because they are parts of the browser program and for security reason. from a browser to another possibilities are different, for some elements there is no options at all. for your input,  you may wrap it in a span , set border to none and style the span instead ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You cannot** :(

---

you may style a regular tag instead :

```css
span {
  float: left;
  border: inset gray 2px;
  background: white;
  line-height: 2em;
  height: 2em;
}

span input {
  border: none;
}

.submit,
.submit input {
  background-color: #337AB7;
  border: solid #337AB7 2px;
  width: 3em;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  display: inline-block;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px white;
}
body {
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span>
   <input type="text" value="(800) 123-456789" /> 
  </span>
  <span class="submit">
   <input type="submit" value="Dial"/><!-- unless this a link , styles to be applied here & span can be skipped -->
  </span>
</p>
```

Comment: The fantastic IE, and our great minds to always find a workaround or a fix :)